# Select Max ID in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I need help.
I'm testing a web system and on a certain page, I need to click on the largest ID number.
Each time a record is generated on that page, a new ID number is generated and I need to be able to always enter the last one.

This is the xpath
//*[@id='dgParametros']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a

The number 2 corresponds to the column where the ID is located. 
When I create another record the new xpath will be

//*[@id='dgParametros']/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/a

Since the new ID number will be inserted in column number 3

Please help!!!

Comment: Is it always the last row in the table? If so, I think you could get away with using `//*[@id='dgParametros']/tbody/tr[last()]/td[1]/a`. If there's <tr> used as a footer you may need something like `[last() - 1]`.

Comment: yessssssss!!!!!!!... Thank you very much, I worked perfectly